# Hide my real ip with Cloudflare

Tags: cloudflare

I have a VPS and I want to hide IP with cloudflare.

```
IP: 127.0.0.1
NS: ns1.domain.com
```

So I created an account and change the nameservers but when I check with ping or whois service, it returns MY ip with the cloudflare nameservers...

```
IP: 127.0.0.1
NS: iam.ns.cloudflare.com
```

Should I change something to dns settings ?

I want something like this:

```
IP: 141.101.116.233 (cloudflare-nginx)
NS: iam.ns.cloudflare.com
```

Comment: Assuming you set it up correctly, it will take a little time for it to update.  If it doesn't, get with CloudFlare support

Comment: `IP: 127.0.0.1`  So much facepalm.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to hide your public IP address? That's silly.

Answer (score 3):

Your previous IP will be cached for a while (possibly days) before it gets updated.

Also, "hiding" public information is easy to get around by people who know what they're doing.

Comment: +1. CloudFlare is a Content Distribution Network (or CDN), **not** a privacy service. I'd suggest researching CDNs as a starting point, as explaining what a CDN does is beyond the scope of ServerFault. Edit to Chris: I'd personally stick this as "not understanding the subject" rather than "non-professional" but each to their own :)

Comment: @CraigWatson While I understand CDN's are not designed as a privacy service, could you explain briefly how somebody could obtain your website's IP address when it's located behind the CDN?